# Does there exists any non trivial linear metric space in which every open ball is not convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, convex-analysis

$\Bbb{R^\omega}=\{(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}: x_n \in \Bbb{R}\}$

$d(x, y) =\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}{(a_j)} \frac{|x_j -y_j|}{1+|x_j -y_j|}$

Then $(\Bbb{R^\omega}, d) $ is a metric space.

I know in a normed space any ball is convex. And it is easy to prove.

The space $(\Bbb{R^\omega}, d) $  is not a normed space, I mean no norm on $\Bbb{R^\omega} $ can induce the metric $d$.

So, I guess in that space, It may be possible to find an open ball which is not convex.

My question :1) Can I pick any open ball to test whether it is convex or not?

2. If no, then is there any linear metric space in which every open ball is not convex?
3. Can we get an example of a linear metric space (not a normed space) in which every open ball is convex?

For the last question can I take $(X, \|•\|)$ be any  normed space and then define a metric $d(x, y) =\sqrt\|x-y\|$. I think it works. Isn't it?

Here $d$ is not scaling equivalent, hence not induced by any norm.

$B_{d}(x_0, r) =\{x\in X : \|x-x_0\|<r^2 \}=B_{\|•\|} (x_0, r^2) $

Hence, every open ball is convex.

Comment: I think you should clarify what you mean by "linear metric space". I think you mean a linear space equipped with a metric that makes the linear space operations continuous.

Comment: $(X, d) $ be a metric space where the underlying set is a linear space.

Comment: What you call a "linear space", people usually call a "vector space."

Comment: @Moishe Kohan, I think I am not the first one who use the term "linear space " instead of "Vector space" See this Wikipedia article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, a standard example is $L^p([0,1])$ for $0 < p < 1$. It is a metric space for
$$d(f,g):= \int_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|^pdx.$$

One can show that if $C$ is a convex open set in this space, then $C= L^p([0,1])$. In particular, not a single open ball is convex.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Would be a nice Christmas gift to actually check it. I wish you and your vector spaces a holly jolly Christmas :D

Answer (score 7):

The example of quantumspace is of course the classical/elegant one. Let me give another one (just for fun). We can pick $\mathbb{R}^2$ and put the "Paris"-metric on it (that is how our topology prof called it 10 years ago). Everytime you want to go anywhere, you have to go to "Paris" first and then you can continue your travel. For us Paris will be the origin. Of course it will depend from where you go to "Paris", meaning on some half-ray we put a different metric.

Let $R=\{ (x,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ : \ x\geq 0 \}$, then we define the following metric
$$ d(x,y) := \begin{cases} \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert,& x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus R, \\ 2\vert x \vert + 2 \vert y \vert.& x,y \in R, \\ 2\vert x \vert + \vert y \vert,& x\in R, y \in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus R, \\ \vert x \vert + 2 \vert y\vert,& x\in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus R, y\in R. \end{cases} $$
I guess that all balls in this metric are non-convex, if not, just add one more half-ray with a different metric.

Comment: Everyone who ever boarded a TGV will understand why this is called the Paris metric (or even more fittingly SNCF metric) ...

Comment: @MaoWao As always, you are spot on :D I did not dare to comment on it myself

Comment: It's not a TVS though, is it?

Comment: @tomasz I will check this evening if I have time. Addition is continuous by the triangle inequality, will think about multiplication.

Comment: Well, the metric is definitely not invariant (which should be true for a linear metric space). Every point other than the origin is isolated, but the origin is not, so addition is not continuous, or am I missing something?

Comment: @tomasz You are right, addition is not continuous as $$ \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} (e_1, \varepsilon e_2) = (e_1, 0)$$ in the product topology, but $$ \liminf_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \ d(e_1, e_1+\varepsilon e_2) = \liminf_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+ }  \ (2 + \sqrt{1+\varepsilon})=3. $$

Answer (score 4):

A simpler example of an “$L_p$” space: $\mathbb R^2$ with the $l_p$ quasi-norm, where $p=\tfrac12$. The quasi-norm is $\|(x,y)\|_p = \sqrt{|x|}+ \sqrt{|y|}$.

I like this example because you can easily draw pictures of the open balls —- they all look like diamonds with concave sides. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#When_0_%3C_p_%3C_1).

Comment: That's a really nice example. Very neat!

Comment: Imho open balls in this metric with radius $r$ are just standard open balls with radius $r^2$, and hence convex. Do I miss something?

Comment: Maybe you meant $d(p,q) = \sqrt{|p_1-q_1|} + \sqrt{|p_2-q_2|} $?

Comment: @daw Indeed, that is what he probably meant (and I misread)

Comment: Yes, the comments are correct. I was thinking of the $\ell_p$ quasi-norm with $p=\tfrac12$, but I wrote down its definition wrong. I’ll fix the answer.